# Using multiprocessing.pool load keras model cause predict "ValueError Tensor Tensor"

Tags: python-3.x, tf.keras

I have saved more than 1000 models for each item. Now I need to load all these models into memory (a dataframe) to do predictions. If I just use "for" loop to load these models, each loading will be 3 seconds slower than the previous model loading. So I try to use multiprocessing.pool (ThreadPool).

But, strangely, using ThreadPool will cause the prediction "ValueError: Tensor Tensor". If using normal loading, the prediction is fine.

I tried thread also got error msg

```
#following code will lead to ValueError
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool
def load_model(stock):
    model_pred.at[0, stock] = keras.models.load_model (
        'C:/Users/chenp/Documents/rqpro/models/{}_model.h5'.format (stock))


pool = Pool(processes=16)
for stock in trade_stocks['stock']:
    pool.map (load_model, (stock,))

#Prediction
for stock in trade_stocks['stock']:
    model = model_pred.loc[0, stock]
    prediction = model.predict(pred_data)

#Get following msg:
ValueError: Tensor Tensor("dense_9/Softmax:0", shape=(?, 2), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.

#Normal code but too low efficient
for stock in trade_stocks['stock']:
    model_pred.at[0, stock] = keras.models.load_model(
           'C:/Users/chenp/Documents/rqpro/models/{}_model.h5'.format(stock))





#Get following msg:
ValueError: Tensor Tensor("dense_9/Softmax:0", shape=(?, 2), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens as Keras is not thread safe. For solving this problem, please use _make_predict_function() before predicting. For detailed answer, please [check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53391618/tensor-tensorpredictions-softmax0-shape-1000-dtype-float32-is-not-an)