# Keras Tensor is not an element of this graph

Tags: python, file, tensorflow, flask, keras

I have Python 3.6.9, Tensorflow 1.14.0 and Jupyter Notebook 5.7.9. I created a neural network in Jupyter Notebook and saved it to a file:

```
model = Sequential([
    Dense(16, input_shape=(2,), activation="relu"),
    Dense(len(classes), activation="softmax")
])

model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop", loss="mse")
# Training, testing, etc...
model.save("model.h5")
```

Now, I would like to load this saved model inside Flask server and predict some output:

```
model = load_model("model.h5")

y = model.predict(np.array([[1, 0]]))
```

However, error appears:

> Tensor Tensor("dense_1/Softmax:0", shape=(?, 8), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.

So I was looking for [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53391618/tensor-tensorpredictions-softmax0-shape-1000-dtype-float32-is-not-an) and modified Flask code:

```
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
model = load_model("model.h5")
model._make_predict_function()

y = model.predict(np.array([[1, 0]]))
```

Now, another error appears:

> Tensor dense_input:0, specified in either feed_devices or fetch_devices was not found in the Graph

I was looking for [solution](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6462) again:

```
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
model = load_model("model.h5")
model._make_predict_function()

global graph
global sess
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
sess = tf.Session()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)

with graph.as_default():
    tf.keras.backend.set_session(sess)
    y = model.predict(np.array([[1, 0]]))
```

Finally no error, but `model.predict` returns absolutely bad (random) results even though Jupyter Notebook returns correct results - maybe pretrained weights in network was deleted? Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution, this code should work:

```
global graph
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
session = tf.keras.backend.get_session()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
session.run(init)
lum_class_nn = load_model("model.h5")

with graph.as_default():
    tf.keras.backend.set_session(session)
    y = model.predict(np.array([[1, 0]]))
```